# How to get duplicate results in two or more joined tables?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have two tables:

1. orders (id);
2. order_items(id, order_id, item_id, quantity)

Let's say I have already selected an order X with 3 different items (A - 1 unit, B - 2 units and C - 1 unit).

I need to get all the orders that have same items and exactly the same quantity of items (in this case:  A - 1 unit, B - 2 units and C - 1 unit and no more or no less :)), excluding an order X.

i made a dump of test tables, so, I hope, for You would be easier to understand, what I'd like to get:) http://nopaste.info/44eb93ae3d.html

lets assume order X = 1, so desired output would be only the order 2, because order 3 has only one item and order 4 has same items as #1, but it has also one item extra, so it is not good :)

Comment: What must happens if an order have the same item than X, and even more items ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the same occurence of each orders in the order_items table, and then compare to the number of item of the searched order:

```
SELECT i2.order_id
FROM order_items i1
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN order_items i2
        ON i2.item_id = i1.item_id 
        AND i2.quantity = i1.quantity
        AND i1.order_id = 1
WHERE i2.order_id  != 1
GROUP BY i2.order_id
HAVING COUNT(i1.order_id) = COUNT(*)
   AND COUNT(i1.order_id) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM order_items WHERE order_id = 1)
```

Note that this query assume that `(order_id, item_id)` is a Key of the `order_items` table.

[I have made a sample test here.](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/1703/how-to-get-duplicate-results-in-two-or-more-joined-tables)

Comment: there was small syntax error. i modified a bit this part: COUNT(CASE WHEN i2.order_id = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), then it returns some orders, that have at least one same item of the order X. this is not what I'd like to get. BTW, in results, there are also some correctly selected orders:)

Comment: You are right, I forgot 'END' to the CASE. If you want an alternative, then do COUNT(CASE WHEN i2.order_id = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) or SUM(CASE WHEN i2.order_id = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END). Else the count will count the 0 too.

Comment: thanks, but if i modify query like You suggested, i get no results at all. something is wrong here :) i executed MyResult part and found that numberOfSameOrder isn't counted correctly(it counts the number of the same items, but not all the items in order) and result of numberOfOrderX is > 0 only in the order X, so "where" clause just cannot work, imho :)

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from orders o
JOIN order_items oi ON o.id = oi.order_id
JOIN (select *
      from orders o2
      JOIN order_items oi2 ON o2.id = oi2.order_id
      WHERE o2.id = @X) sub
ON oi.quantity = sub.quantity
AND oi.item_id = sub.item_id
WHERE o.id <> @X
```

EDIT:

```
select *
from orders o
JOIN order_items oi ON o.id = oi.order_id
JOIN (select *
      from orders o2
      JOIN order_items oi2 ON o2.id = oi2.order_id
      WHERE o2.id = @X) sub
ON oi.quantity = sub.quantity
AND oi.item_id = sub.item_id
AND NOT EXISTS (select 1 
                from order_items 
                where order_id = o.id 
                and concat(item_id,quantity) not in (select concat(itemid,quantity)
                                                     from order_items
                                                     where order_id = o.id))
WHERE o.id <> @X
```

Comment: same here, i get exactly same results like in Scopri0's query. these queries get orders, that have at least one same item of the order X. this is wrong